# Jasny BootStrap, Set Value for Input type="file"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

im using Jasny Bootstrap library

```
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/
```

im using the file input field.

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Site Logo</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput" id="fileInputSiteLogo">
                            <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div>
                            <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="siteLogo"></span>
                            <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

Problem is i want to set the value in to that.

for normal TextBox in jQuery i know it is

```
$('#inputselector').val($phpVariable);
```

and in HTML it is

```
value = "<?php echo $phpVariable ?>"
```

i have data coming from database and i want to set the existing value to this file input field.

Please tell for both HTML and jQuery if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

Comment: @pozs
im aware of that, but it is the bootstrap file input. it is masked over. the real input field is hidden.
So it is not the same as normal input type.

Comment: If you want to display a text *before* any file selection, you probably want to display it in `$(".fileinput-filename")` (which is span, not an input) -- but that could be misleading (no upload will happen, if the user won't select any file). http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

Comment: Yes, i dont want the upload. i only want to show the name of the uploaded file in text box field which is span.. 
There is a way through jQuery. if i change classes and add through .text. 
But i want to avoid that lengthy process. want to see if there is any other easy way like any function or something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file name is displayed in `.fileinput-filename`.

```
<span class="fileinput-filename"><?php echo $phpVariable ?></span>
```

or using JavaScript

```
var filename = "<?php echo $phpVariable ?>";
$('#myFileUpload .fileinput-filename').text(filename);
```

*This example doesn't do proper [escaping](http://php.net/htmlentities).*